# Change the look and feel of the fancyBox media?

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a got a site with fancyBox installed and a gallery with both images and videos. 
Yet the look of the images is a lot different than the videos.

Here is the gallery in question:
http://imaginefilmscommunication.com/site/#portfolio

(The only video presently is the last one in the gallery)
I want the videos to look like the images (Big white border on the bottom instead of rounded black rectangle...)

Is this done in the JavaScript or in css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the videos to look like the images, then use the same ***class selector*** for both, images and videos and add `media: {}` to the `helpers` API option like (using your current code) :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        },
        media: {} //<== added for videos
    },
    padding: 0,
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
        this.title = '<h4>' + this.title + '</h4><hr class="gray">' + $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
});
```

then change the class selector in your (videos) html from `fancybox-media` to `fancybox` so this

```
<a class="project-wrp fancybox-media" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rel="group7" href="https://vimeo.com/34134308">...</a>
```

becomes into this

```
<a class="project-wrp fancybox" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" rel="group7" href="https://vimeo.com/34134308">...</a>
```

**Notice** that

```
helpers: {
    ...
    media: {} //<== added for videos
}
```

won't have any effect on the images so you can combine the option safely.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8Jmg/show/)**  (second thumb opens video)

Comment: I see it works on the page you added, exactly what I aim to do. Yet I don't have that script in my main page. Where exactly do I add the media: {}?

Comment: @user2916877 : well, you do have that script in your page here http://imaginefilmscommunication.com/site/js/settings.js